# Permission Denied error when trying to compile hello world C program in Mac terminal

Tags: c, macos, terminal, permission-denied

I'm trying to compile a hello world c program in the mac terminal and I am generating these errors:

```
mysource.c:1:19: error: /usr/local/include/stdio.h: Permission denied
mysource.c: In function ‘main’:
mysource.c:3: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
```

This is what I typed into the terminal (mysource is the name of the .c file):

```
MacBook-Pro:~ drummer0014$ gcc mysource.c -o mysource
```

I had xcode 3 installed and generated the same error so I just installed xcode 4.2 today and am having the same error. I am on a macbook running snow leopard. 
I also tried typing gcc and then dragging the file into the terminal so that it would have the full path but I get the same error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

When I typed gcc --verbose mysource.c -o mysource
Here is what I received:

```
    Using built-in specs.
    Target: i686-apple-darwin10
    Configured with: /private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.1~3/src/configure --disable-         checking --enable-werror --prefix=/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2 --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-prefix=llvm- --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin10 --enable-         llvm=/private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.1~3/dst-llvmCore/Developer/usr/local --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin10- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin10 --target=i686-apple-darwin10 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
    gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00)
     /usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/cc1 -quiet -v -imultilib    x86_64 -iprefix /usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/ -D__DYNAMIC__ mysource.c -fPIC -quiet -dumpbase mysource.c -mmacosx-version-min=10.6.8 -m64 -mtune=core2 -auxbase mysource -version -o /var/folders/7r/7rMZhHx3F0WhnoyEK1zUgE+++TI/-Tmp-//ccaqeJkd.s
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/../../../../i686-apple-darwin10/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/../../../../i686-apple-darwin10/include"
    #include "..." search starts here:
    #include <...> search starts here:
     /usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/include
     /usr/local/include
     /Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/include
     /usr/include
     /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
     /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
    End of search list.
    GNU C version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00) (i686-apple-    darwin10)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00).
    GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=150 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
    Compiler executable checksum: e787fa4ffdc9e78ad5e913828c220d85
    mysource.c:1:19: error: /usr/local/include/stdio.h: Permission denied
    mysource.c: In function ‘main’:
    mysource.c:3: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
```

Comment: include a bit of source, particularly your includes wherever main is

Comment: what does the source look like in `main()`? specifically, anything to do with `printf`

Comment: My comment does not fit here in the comment column.  See rather my answer below.

Comment: Run the above ls command to get the permissions on the directory where the header files are. Then read the man pages for ls and chmod

Comment: If you had Xcode 3 with its Unix Development Tools, and then installed Xcode 4.2, you have to install its Command Line Tools, or various things can go wrong. But usually not _this_ thing…

Comment: @abarnert, I think you're thinking of Xcode 4.3. 4.2 still installs the UNIX Development tools from Installer.app.

Comment: @KenThomases: Ah, you're right. 4.1 gives you the option of whether or not to install during the Installer, 4.3 has the Downloads tab inside Preferences, but 4.2 seems to just install them automatically. Gotta love the consistency here. Anyway, they all install to /usr/bin, so, despite the fact that a mismatch can cause a problem, it's still probably not relevant.

Answer (score 3):

STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED is sort of correct, but I wouldn't change the permissions on `/usr/local` just yet. On a typical Mac OS X installation, `/usr/local` is not used for anything. If anything goes there, it's third-party software.

So, the real question is why GCC is looking for (and finding) headers there. I suspect it's because you're not running the GCC from Xcode, but that you have a third-party version of GCC in /usr/local.

What does `which gcc` report?  What does `echo $PATH` show?

When you installed Xcode, did you install the UNIX Development component? If not, then you have to access the tools in /Developer/usr/bin, either explicitly or by adding that directory early in your PATH. If you did install that component, then make sure that `/usr/bin` and `/usr/sbin` are earlier in your PATH than `/usr/local/bin` or `/usr/local/sbin`.

---

Update:

Hmm, the interesting part of your `gcc --verbose` output is:

```
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/include
 /usr/local/include
 /Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
```

I just checked on my system and `llvm-gcc-4.2` (the compiler that's actually being used) produces the same search list here. So, I guess it's normal that the compiler would look in `/usr/local/include` for headers – and look there before `/usr/include` – it's just abnormal that you would have any headers there.

My recommendation is that you move aside `/usr/local`:

```
sudo mv /usr/local /usr/local.bak
```

or at least `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib`:

```
sudo mv /usr/local/include /usr/local/include.bak
sudo mv /usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib.bak
```

Whatever third-party software originally installed that stuff may break, but at least then you'd know what it was.  More likely, you will never notice any problems from doing that.

Comment: which gcc reports:  /usr/bin/gcc  echo $PATH shows: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin

Comment: I'm not sure if I installed the UNIX development component or not. I installed the standard xcode disk image. I am very new to this stuff and I don't understand what you mean by putting that directory early in the PATH.

Comment: OK, so the `which gcc` result is good. What does `gcc --version` show? Actually, please edit your question to show the output from `gcc --verbose mysource.c -o mysource`. It's weird that your PATH has `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin` at the beginning, but I don't think it will cause a problem. The UNIX Development component is enabled by default in the Xcode 3.x and 4.2 installers, but it does present you an opportunity to disable them. If you didn't disable them you're probably fine.

Comment: @KenThomases: Exactly right on "the real question". The Unix Development Tools (or Command Line Tools, depending on your version) go into /usr, not /usr/local. It's hard to imagine anyone could build gcc without realizing it… but there are some pre-built gcc packages that install into /usr/local, which sometimes come as part of big mega-packages for things like scientific computing, and then you can pull post-4.2 gcc versions from homebrew.

Comment: I typed gcc --verbose mysource.c -o mysource into the terminal and this is what I got:

Comment: Your post didn't come through. Better to edit your question and post the output there. Comments aren't good for output logs.

Comment: I edited the question. Sorry for the formatting of the code, this is my first post on this site.

Comment: Thanks and no problem. I edited the formatting. I've also updated my answer with some analysis and suggestions.

Comment: Good patience, great answer, wish I could +1 it again.

Answer (score 0):

Did your `mysource.c` look just like this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("hello, world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

If not, would you list `mysource.c` so that we can look at it?

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED, `#include "x"` behaves differently from `#include <x>`. Since the error message indicates an attempt to read what should be a Standard header from a prefix other than where `gcc` is installed, this might be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

[**mlp**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/99124) was pointing out a very relevant fact. If you use `#include "stdio.h"` instead of `#include <stdio.h>` the search (order etc) for the headers will differ. Since this is a standard header, try first using `#include <stdio.h>` to recompile. If that doesn't help, I think we have to assume it's a permission issue.

---

It's quite obvious that your user cannot access the location in which the headers for `gcc` reside, i.e. `/usr/local/include/stdio.h` in particular. Make sure to `sudo chmod o+rX /usr/local/include` to grant anyone read access to this location (you will need super-user rights to do this!), then try to compile again.

Now the reason for:

```
mysource.c:3: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
```

is quite obvious then as well. If the header file could not be read because of a permission issue, it cannot be included and C defaults to standard behavior, assuming a function returning `int` and any number of parameters.

---

Now I'm not 100% about the semantics of permissions here, but it's possible that some of the folders higher up in the hierarchy also need fixing, i.e. `/usr/local` and `/usr`. But normally these would have relatively relaxed permissions at least for something as mundane as the header files under `include`.